# VBA Winsock code working well in windows 7 excel - not working anymore in 64bit (Excel 365)

Tags: excel, vba, winsock, winsock2

For an excel application that was coded 15 years ago and was working very well until Windows 7 - it's not working anymore on Windows 10.

Reason: VBA code contains a socket from MSWinsockLib which I think does not work in 64bit excel

```
   public mysck As MSWinsockLib.Winsock
   Set mysck = New Winsock
```

Running above in Excel 360 fails to create a socket. Is there easy way to define new socket easily? I heard ws2_32.dll could work - but I'm not a developer (don't have VS) so I was not able to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: `MSWinsockLib.Winsock` is located in MSWINSCK.ocx, which is indeed a 32-bit control. It must be installed, registered, and the consumer must be 32-bit.

Comment: Are there any other constraints? Can it be any type of socket that works on a 64 bit? Is there authentication involved?

Comment: @QHarr - No authentication involved, and I've not seen other constraints in the code

Comment: You might find something here: https://www.example-code.com/excel/websocket.asp